# Campos de dialog aparecendo quando pagina atualiza

Tags: php, jquery

Caros, inseri alguns `divs` para trabalhar com `dialog` e tabs , esses com uso de jquery.
Tudo esta funcionando bem, porem toda vez que entro ou atualizo a página, os campos que possuem um `dialog` "por trás" dão uma "piscada" mostrando rapidamente o resultado do `dialog` e retornando a página normal. Não sei se consegui ser claro, esses dialogs que "piscam" apontam para uma `div` a qual possui um código php para listar uma tabela.
Desde já, agradeço a atenção.

Comment: coloca o código fonte para ter uma ideia

Comment: Consegue postar algumas imagens pra exemplificar também?

Comment: opa, consegui arrumar, basta colocar o script onload=function(){
document.body.style.visibility="visible"
} e fazer o body ficar com visibility:hidden no css.

Comment: obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Coloque como resposta e marque como resolvido

Answer (score 1):

Consegui arrumar, basta colocar o script

```
onload=function(){ 
    document.body.style.visibility="visible" 
}
```

e fazer o body ficar com `visibility:hidden` no css.